# AngularJS - Strategy Design Pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Is there a clean way to implement the strategy design pattern or something like it in AngularJS? I am basically building up a dashboard, but there are different user levels in my system. So some will have different dashboards, which require different functions and whatnot.

What I was looking to do is swap out the `controller` based on the user's access level. I would have something like a `baseDashboardCtrl` for the common things, then using `angular.extend()`, I would create their respective "extended" dashboard controllers with the different data and functions. I suppose I'll create different partials too, but I know how to do that.

I'd like to go this route so that I don't fill up a single controller with all this code, when it's not going to be needed for some access levels.